# Forwarded in-place construction and list-initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, object-construction, list-initialization

By forwarded in-place construction, I take to mean [std::allocator::construct](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/construct) and the various emplace methods, e.g., [std::vector::emplace_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back). I just find that forwarded in-place construction in C++ does not (unable to?) take advantage of the list-initialization syntax. As a result, it seems one can never forward in-place construct an aggregate. I just want to make sure whether forwarded in-place construction does not support list-initialization and hence aggregate types. Is this due to the limitation of the language? Could someone provide reference to the standard concerning this issue? Following is an illustration:

While we can do in-place construction directly like

```
int(*p)[3] = ...;
new(p) int[3]{1, 2, 3};
```

we cannot do forwarded in-place construction like

```
std::allocator<int[3]> allo;
allo.construct(p, 1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: something like `Type object((foo, bar), anotherFoo, anotherBar);`?

Comment: My original statement about the question is unclear. Updated now.

Comment: Have you tried writing a forwarding constructor-type-thing that uses `{}`?

Comment: @Yakk It works on GCC and clang. See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/833a11295113578b. But I'm not sure whether this is actually allowed according to the standard. If it is permitted, I see no reason in the standard library using what it is using now instead of this.

Comment: `std::allocator::construct` (and `std::allocator_traits::construct`) are specified to use `()` rather than `{}`, and must remain so for compatibility reasons (`vector<int>(10, 10)` vs. `vector<int>{10, 10}`). There's [an LWG issue](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2089) to make it fall back to using `{}` if `()` doesn't work.

Comment: @T.C. I get your point. It is convincing. The fallback to `{}` may still surprise the programmers in some cases :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While `{}` has been called uniform initialization syntax, it is far from universal.

take these two examples:

```
size_t a = 3;
size_t b = 1;
std::vector<size_t> v1{a,b};
std::vector<size_t> v2(a,b);
```

in the first case, we construct a vector containing two elements, `3` and `1`.

In the second case, we create a vector containing `1,1,1` -- 3 copies of `1`.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d23a2ea2b6cef5d).

So `{}` based construction can cause a different behavior than `()` based construction in some cases.  What more, in the above case, there is no way to reach the "3 copies of 1" syntax using `{}` construction (that I know of).  But the `{3,2}` case can be handled by simply explicitly creating an initializer list and passing it to `()`.

As most types that take initializer lists can be emplace constructed by explicitly passing in an initializer list, and the C++ standard library was designed for types with constructors more than types without them, the C++ standard library nearly uniformly emplace constructs using `()` and not `{}`.

The downside is that types that want to be list-initialized cannot be emplaced via this mechanism.

In theory, `list_emplace` methods that construct using `{}` instead could be added to each interface.  I encourage you to propose that!

Comment: You'd have to add `list_construct` to allocators too. I'm not sure I like that direction.

Comment: @T.C. I saw the other direction (where `construct` falls back on list construction if bracket construction fails).  That seems error prone: `emplace(1,2)` putting a `2` while `emplace(1,2,3)` putting a `1,2,3` seems utter insanity.

Comment: That's a good point. I believe there was a similar discussion about the semantics of list-initialization during the C++11 standardization process that lead to the "`initializer_list` constructor is always preferred for `{}`" rule.

Comment: I guess it would be a good idea to automatically switch between `{}` and `()` according to whether the supplied type is an aggregate or not.

Comment: @Yakk `emplace` and `list_emplace` are different in name. This makes it impossible to write generic template code using a uniform method name.

Comment: @Yakk Well, I just realize that such generic code, if possible to write, would then have confusing behaviors :(

Comment: @Lingxi Yep.  There is no universal way to initialize data in C++, despite attempts of C++11.

Comment: "there is no way to reach the "3 copies of 1" syntax using {} construction" Is `std::vector<int>{3, 1, std::allocator<int>{}}` cheating? ;)

Answer (score 3):

`std::allocator`'s `construct()` (and also the default implementation provided by `std::allocator_traits`) are specified to use `()`: `::new((void *)p) U(std::forward<Args>(args)...)` (see [allocator.members]/p12, [allocator.traits.members]/p5).

It is impractical to change it to `{}` at this point, because it would silently break existing code:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> foo;
foo.emplace_back(10, 10); // add a vector of ten 10s with (); two 10s with {}
```

There is [an LWG issue](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2089) to make it fall back to using `{}` if `()` doesn't work. We'll have to see whether the committee agrees with that direction.

@Yakk points out the potential drawbacks with this approach:

```
foo.emplace_back(10); // ten 0s
foo.emplace_back(10, 10); // ten 10s
foo.emplace_back(10, 10, 10); // three(!) 10s
```

A similar issue (see Appendix B of [N2215](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2215.pdf)) led to the decision that list-initialization will always prefer `initializer_list` constructors.

Comment: Indeed, (unaware of that issue), I implemented that fallback [myself](https://github.com/Arcoth/Constainer/blob/master/impl/BasicVector.hxx#L212). It doesn't even break code.